# Is KDE 4 still available? Or how to use the look of KDE 4 on Plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I know the latest version is `KDE Plasma 5`, but I really dislike its look and I want to use `KDE 4`. I found that `KDE 3` is available as `Trinity DE`, being a continuation of the old version.

Is there something similar for `KDE 4`? The problem is not the software, but especially the look.

I am unable to find how to install `KDE 4` on new Ubuntu, or how to use the `KDE 4` design on `KDE 5`.

Can you help me? Thank you!

*Using latest version of Ubuntu.*

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) replaced Qt4, and naturally KDE4 requires Qt4 so it's EOL/gone.

Comment: To answer the *design* features you're looking, may require more details. I'm one who loved KDE4, and wasn't a fan of KDE5 on coming out, however I've been able to achieve what I loved in KDE4 with modern KDE5 for some time now, but the features you miss/want may differ to what I loved (& can now achieve pretty easily with a modern Kubuntu install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019)

For more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295.

Qt5 (*introduced 19-Dec-2012*) replaced Qt4, and naturally KDE4 requires Qt4 so it's EOL/gone.